# Active Cell not highlighting with CellPainting

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

(First time posting, please be gentle.)

I have a DataGridView on my form, that makes the cells in the current row and column appear highlighted. I also added a CellPainting part to give the active cell a thicker border. The code goes like this:

```
Private Sub DGV_CellPainting(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs) Handles DGV.CellPainting
        Try
            Dim CRow As Integer = DGV.CurrentCell.RowIndex
            Dim CCol As Integer = DGV.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex
            If e.RowIndex = CRow AndAlso e.ColumnIndex = CCol Then
                Using BBrush As Brush = New SolidBrush(Color.Black)
                    Using BPen As Pen = New Pen(BBrush, 2)
                        Dim CBRect As Rectangle = e.CellBounds
                        CBRect.Width -= 1
                        CBRect.Height -= 1
                        CBRect.X = rectDimensions.Left
                        CBRect.Y = rectDimensions.Top
                        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(BPen, CBRect)
                        e.Handled = True
                    End Using
                End Using
            End If
        Catch
        End Try
    End Sub
```

The above works fine in the sense it adds the border to the cell, however the active cell does not show up as highlighted, just white. I do not understand as there is no specification of FillRectangle() or of any other colours than the black border, so I assumed it would keep the cell colour the same, but it does not go blue like the other cells in its row and column.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line of your code `e.Handled = True` tells VB.NET not to continue with any future event handling, thus, the cell is not painted blue. If you remove that line, it should work fine.

Edit: Your border is not applied completely because in your code, you use the `Graphics` object provided by the event, which represents the graphics **of the cell**, but not of the entire `DataGridView`. Thus, you cannot draw outside of the cell with the graphics object obtained by the event. And the border you were trying to draw happens to be partially outside of the cell. So here is a sample which should work as intended:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellPainting(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellPainting
    If DataGridView1.CurrentCell Is Nothing Then Return
    Dim graphics As Graphics = DataGridView1.CreateGraphics()
    Dim CRow As Integer = DataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex
    Dim CCol As Integer = DataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex
    If e.RowIndex = CRow AndAlso e.ColumnIndex = CCol Then
        Using BBrush As Brush = New SolidBrush(Color.Black)
            Using BPen As Pen = New Pen(BBrush, 3)
                Dim CBRect As Rectangle = e.CellBounds
                CBRect.Width -= 1
                CBRect.Height -= 1
                graphics.DrawRectangle(BPen, CBRect)
            End Using
        End Using
    End If
    graphics.Dispose()
End Sub
```

Here, we use the `CreateGraphics()` method to obtain a `Graphics` object which represents the entire `DataGridView`. And, just another piece of advice, use logical statements instead of `Try`/`Catch` if possible, as I've done in the above code (first line). In addition, you should not leave the `Catch` block empty, as it makes it difficult to solve runtime errors. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It now shows as selected, however the border is not completely applied, only the top and left (of the cell) are coloured black, so it has not completely worked, unfortunately.

Comment: @Alex Just edited it, hope it solves your issue!

Comment: Thank-you very much for your time! However it is still not working properly. The border of the active cell will not change to the desired thickness, and the bottom and right side of the cell are left unformatted if you navigate without actually clicking on the cell. Sorry if you feel I am 'wasting' your time, I just really want this to work :)